# ExtJS : count number of values for json key

Tags: json, extjs, coffeescript

I'm working on an ExtJS MVC style application written in coffescript and I'd like to return just the number of values assigned to "key2".

In this example I'd like to get the number 2 back.

However, in the example below instead I get "11". Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
// JSON
"data" : [{
     "key1" : "value",
     "key2" : ["valu1", "valu2"]
]}

//Model
Ext.define("Test.model.Values",
    extend: "Ext.data.Model"

   fields: [
       name: "key1"
       type: "string"
   ,
       name: "values"
       type: "string"
       convert: (value, record) ->
         return record.get("key2").length
   ]
```

)

Comment: Somewhere in your code (though not the code above) 1 is being added 1 *as strings*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
type: "string"
```

on a field that holds an array such as:

```
["valu1", "valu2"]
```

will force the value to a string:

```
"valu1,valu2"
```

which happens to be 11 characters long in this case.

First you will need to define a field for "key2" so that it will be read from your data, then just be sure not to explicitly set the type.

```
fields: [{
   name: "key1",
   type: "string",
},{
   name: "key2"
},{
   name: "values",
   convert: function(value, record){
     return record.get("key2").length
   }
}]
```